# How to check which items in an asp:Treeview are checked client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp page that has a treeview control on it, with checkboxes.  I want to be able to check client side (javascript) which items have been checked.

Now when I view the source of the page, the tree is made up of table elements and I see this on a checked item:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="TreeView1n0CheckBox" id="TreeView1n0CheckBox" checked="checked" />
```

So I could loop around all the `<input>` elements, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this (and yes it would be easier on the Server, but I want to do this on the client).

The other thing I need to figure out is how I get back to the ID of the item in the Treeview.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the checked ones, convert to an array, then use map to get their IDs.

```
var CheckedElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')).map(function(x){ return x.getAttribute('id') });
```